# PHP: strings automatically converted to float and gives negative numbers

Tags: php

I have a PHP code that will compute the balance of the quantity but it gives me a negative value as a balance quantity as shown in the image below.

[image: var_dump result of $balance]

I tried to check the quantities if what's causing the problem and try to var_dump the quantity. after checking using var_dump, it shows that the data type of my quantity is **string** while my balance quantity is **float**.

so far, I have my code below:

```
    $query_po_quantity = mysqli_query($new_conn, "SELECT quantity, po_number FROM purchase_order WHERE supplier_name = '$supplier_name' AND category_name = '$category_name' AND activity = '$activity' AND description = '$description'");

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_po_quantity);

    $po_quantity = $row['quantity'];
    $po_number = $row['po_number'];

    $query_rr_quantity = mysqli_query($new_conn, "SELECT SUM(total_received) AS quantity FROM receiving_reports WHERE po_number = '$po_number' AND category_name = '$category_name' AND activity = '$activity' AND description = '$description'");

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_rr_quantity);
    $rr_quantity = $row['quantity'];

   $balance = $po_quantity - $rr_quantity;
   $supplier_name = preg_replace('/\\\\/', '', $supplier_name);


   echo $po_quantity.' - '.$rr_quantity.' = '.$balance.'<br />';
```

This is the output:

[image: output shows negative balance]

how can I get the actual balance?

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're getting an incorrect result when calculating `0.42 - 0.420000000000000000004` is due to errors with [floating point precision](http://floating-point-gui.de/). This is due to the way floating point numbers are stored, and both MySQL and PHP are susceptible to floating point errors if done incorrectly, but they also both have ways to prevent them when you do need highly precise calculations. With floating point types [only the approximate value is stored](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html) and attempts to treat them as exact values in comparisons may lead to problems.

For PHP, this means you need to use either [the arbitrary precision math functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php) or [gmp functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.gmp.php). For MySQL, you need to be storing the numbers using the `DECIMAL` format with the desired precision you require.

First thing's first, you need to change the data type of your column in MySQL to `DECIMAL`, not a string. Strings are inappropriate to store numbers. Even if you were using a `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE` to store your values 
your code may have actually worked, because these values likely would have been rounded.

Next, seeing as the value `0.420000000000000000004` came from a string stored in your database, I'm assuming the error stems from whatever calculations you did using PHP beforehand when you were calculating the value to be inserted. You will need to update this code to use precise math.

Answer (score 0):

Use [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php):

```
$rr_quantity = number_format($row['quantity'], 2);
```

Comment: I tried this but it returns to zero even though it has still a balance.

Answer (score 0):

Float variable range 1.7E-308 and 1.7E+308 so it's give 15 digits of accuracy. Use number format